# Can't create the right pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

So, given a dataframe with a column called travel time that contains a string like this: 'x h y min', e.g. `5 h 12 min`. Sometimes, when travel time is less than one hour, it looks like this ' x min', i.e. `12 min`. So I'm trying to find a pattern that will give me the numbers from this strings.

I'm using `re`:

```
re.findall(r'(\d{1,2} h)?\s\d{1,2}\smin', mystring)
```

It finds only hours and never finds minutes. Any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: Yeah, `re.findall(r'(\d{1,2}\s*h)?\s+(\d{1,2}\s*min)', mystring)` might do. If you need a more definitive answer, please explain what your data looks like, supply some examples with expected output.

Comment: I've given an example at the top of the question. Your pattern also finds a space and adds it to the answer...

Comment: Sorry, you have no example. You have some strange `x h y min`.  What space do you mean?

Comment: The sample format of string is, for example  ` 5 h 12 min`

Comment: So, do you want `(?:(\d+)\s*h\s+)?(\d+)\s*min`? See https://regex101.com/r/v0ZZzk/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
(?:(\d+)\s*h\s+)?(\d+)\s*min
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0ZZzk/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A(%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*h%5Cs%2B)%3F(%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*min):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:(\d+)\s*h\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `h` - a `h` char
  - `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\s*min` - 0+ whitespaces and `min`.

In Pandas, you may use `df['col'].str.findall(r'(?:(\d+)\s*h\s+)?(\d+)\s*min')`, or something like that.